# To change the node's name to have a unique list python

Tags: python-2.7, graph, nodes, networkx

I have a problem. Should I create a series of graphs with the barabasi_albert_graph function that is in the library called NetworkX in Python; I should bring all nodes of the graph in a list but so that if I have two graphs one with 5 nodes and one with 10 nodes.  I would like to have a unique list so made [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7 , 8,9,10,11,12,13,14]. The first 5 represent those of the first graph and the 10 the others. Instead I find having [0,1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]. How can I do to have the first list so that for example if I write 11 in G gives me True?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the labels using `convert_node_labels_to_integers` like this

```
In [1]: import networkx as nx         

In [2]: G = nx.barabasi_albert_graph(10,3)

In [3]: H = nx.convert_node_labels_to_integers(G,first_label=100)

In [4]: G.nodes()
Out[4]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]

In [5]: H.nodes()
Out[5]: [100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109]
```